# How can I apply CSS to this div class?

Tags: html, css, class

I am trying to make an image be 300px width in CSS.  I created a div class around the image "mainpic" in HTML, and then in CSS, I did .mainpic and width:300px; but it's not changing sizes.  Any ideas why the CSS is not applying to this div class? Thank you and code below!

Here's the HTML (minus head section):

```
 <body>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="info.html">Information</a></li>
   <li><a href="sources.html">Sources</a></li>
</ul>
 <h1>Katherine Graham </h1>
 <h2> Silver Spoon to CEO</p>
 <a href="https://www.washingtonpost.com/">Democracy Dies In the Dark</a>
 <br>
 <div class="mainpic">
 <img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/licensed-image?q=tbn:ANd9GcR42mPHUzh3APxp1Q8iK6BiQNns98VuwX9zk2nQvukALjFAc8207NEMfcOES8Qe" alt="Katherine Graham">
 <div>
 <caption>Katherine Graham</caption>
</body>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
h1{
color:red;
font-size: 50px;
text-decoration: underline;
}
h2 {
font-size: 25px;
}
ul li {
display: inline;
background-color:;
margin: 10px;
border-radius: 25%;
border-color:khaki;
padding: 25px;
border: 25px;
width: 90px;
list-style-type: none;
}
body {
background-color: antiquewhite;
}
.mainpic {
width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: You're only setting the width of the div. You also have to specify the width of the image inside it:
.mainpic img {
            width: 100%;
}
Also, not relevant, but one of your ending tags is wrong (silver spoon...). you have to end it with a </h2>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `width` for img also, otherwise it would keep its original width.

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
}
ul li {
  display: inline;
  background-color: ;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 25%;
  border-color: khaki;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 25px;
  width: 90px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.mainpic {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="info.html">Information</a></li>
  <li><a href="sources.html">Sources</a></li>
</ul>
<h1>Katherine Graham </h1>
<h2> Silver Spoon to CEO</p>
<a href="https://www.washingtonpost.com/">Democracy Dies In the Dark</a>
<br>
<div class="mainpic">
<img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/licensed-image?q=tbn:ANd9GcR42mPHUzh3APxp1Q8iK6BiQNns98VuwX9zk2nQvukALjFAc8207NEMfcOES8Qe" alt="Katherine Graham" width="100%">
<div>
<caption>Katherine Graham</caption>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your container width .mainpic is already taking 300px;
Try to add .mainpic img {width:100%}.
This will work for sure.